# Is mkdir atomic over sshfs?

Tags: sshfs

I am using `mkdir` as a locking mechanism, and to my knowledge `mkdir` is atomic, but it is not atomic over `nfs`. So my question is simple, is `mkdir` atomic over `sshfs`?

Comment: What are the actual issues over NFS? I can't find any details on this. One thing I would be suspicious of over sshfs is that it doesn't seem to provide any way to work relative to a directory handle (fchdir, mkdirat, and such), so it's by default going to rely on the full textual path of the directory you're creating a directory in.

Comment: It is atomic via NFS, but since clients cache the directory structures, it cannot be counted on as a locking mechanism.

Comment: I think the answer is going to depend substantially on whether you're trying to guarantee atomicity between processes on one machine or across a network. Can you clarify the use case?

Comment: Across a network

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is enabled or disabled by default, but mkdir can be cached:

http://goo.gl/QIW4V (cache_mkdir)

Even though the mkdir command itself looks atomic and thread safe enough...

http://goo.gl/LC1Ze (sshfs_mkdir)

http://goo.gl/NHkNH (sftp_request_send)

I would go out on a limb and say that mkdir over sshfs is **not** atomic, because of the caching.